# Are PrimeReact 4 and React 17 compatible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, migration, addeventlistener, primereact

Good morning all,

I was wondering if anyone has a migration path from an older version of PrimeReact (v4) to work with React 17. We are trying to update our project to React 17, but the Menu component appears to have [a “document.addEventListener” built right into it](https://github.com/primefaces/primereact/blob/4.2.2/src/components/menu/Menu.js#L158). [React 17 moves most event delegation away from the document root to individual nodes.](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/08/10/react-v17-rc.html#changes-to-event-delegation)

Ideally we would first update our version of React and then update our version of PrimeReact. Is PrimeReact incompatible with React 17? If so, is there a way to maintain the theming of nova-light when updating from v4 to a more modern version? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't think so I think PrimeReact 7 is React 17 compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so I think PrimeReact 7 is React 17 compatible.

PrimeReact 8 is React 18 compatible.